# How to read data from Azure Blob using SAS key in .net

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

Hello I am trying to access Azure Blob with SAS token to get data from the blob, this is what I have tried.

I am very new to this so have no idea how it should work

this is what I have tried so far.

could you suggest if this is the right way to get data from the Blob and how to resolve this error I am getting please

Error is

[image]

This is the code written sofar

```
namespace BlobQuickstartV12
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            const string sasToken = "sasToken";
          
                var blobUri = new System.Uri("https://xx.blob.xx.xx.net/xxxx?sp=ral&st=2021-07-28T22:29:14Z&se=2021-08-26T06:29:14Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=ZQ%2Bl5yZ2JpEb7TwnWGBNz9hSjGTZr3ZarSPaQ1ssz48%3D");

                var blobUriBuilder = new System.UriBuilder(blobUri)
                {
                    Query = sasToken
                };

                var authorizedBlobUri = blobUriBuilder.Uri;
                var blobClient = new Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient(authorizedBlobUri);

            
            var getBlobResponse = await blobClient.DownloadContentAsync(); //ERROR HERE
            Console.WriteLine("Read blob successfully", getBlobResponse.Value);

          
        }
    }
}
```

Error

```
Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:cbde76c1-b01e-008e-657c-aa7496000999
Time:2021-09-15T21:55:49.0166554Z
Status: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed

Additional Information:
AuthenticationErrorDetail: Signature not valid in the specified time frame: Start [Wed, 28 Jul 2021 22:29:14 GMT] - Expiry [Thu, 26 Aug 2021 06:29:14 GMT] - Current [Wed, 15 Sep 2021 21:55:49 GMT]

Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:cbde76c1-b01e-008e-657c-aa7496000000
Time:2021-09-15T21:55:49.0166554Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature not valid in the specified time frame: Start [Wed, 28 Jul 2021 22:29:14 GMT] - Expiry [Thu, 26 Aug 2021 06:29:14 GMT] - Current [Wed, 15 Sep 2021 21:55:49 GMT]</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>

Headers:
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: cbde76c1-b01e-008e-657c-aa7496000000
x-ms-error-code: AuthenticationFailed
Date: Wed, 15 Sep 2021 21:55:48 GMT
Content-Length: 544
Content-Type: application/xml
'
```

Any suggestions please

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

You should be able initialise the BlobClient using 'AzureSasCredential' like so:

```
var client = new BlobClient(new Uri("https://xx.blob.xx.xx.net/xxxx"), new AzureSasCredential("sp=ral&st=2021-07-28T22:29:14Z&se=2021-08-26T06:29:14Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=ZQ%2Bl5yZ2JpEb7TwnWGBNz9hSjGTZr3ZarSPaQ1ssz48%3D"));
```

Edit:

I just read the error, your SAS key has expired:

Signature not valid in the specified time frame: Start [Wed, 28 Jul 2021 22:29:14 GMT] - Expiry [Thu, 26 Aug 2021 06:29:14 GMT]

Comment: Thank you Phil, when I add above line and amended the new key, it returns me with a new error:System.ArgumentException: 'You cannot use AzureSasCredential when the resource URI also contains a Shared Access Signature: <<MYURI>>
You can remove the shared access signature by creating a BlobUriBuilder, setting BlobUriBuilder.Sas to null, and calling BlobUriBuilder.ToUri.'

Comment: I have been given with this URI I cannot amend anything/remove from the URI as the error says.

Comment: Hi Auo, make sure that you only put the domain in the URI, not the query (everything after the question mark which contains the SAS). So from the above example the URI = 'https://xx.blob.xx.xx.net/xxxx' and the AzureSasCredential = 'sp=ral&st=2021-07-28T22:29:14Z&se=2021-08-26T06:29:14Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=ZQ%2Bl5yZ2JpEb7TwnWGBNz9hSjGTZr3ZarSPaQ1ssz48%3D'. I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been provided with a URL containing the SAS token you have all you need to access the blob resource.
You only need the Uri object in the constructor on the BlobClient.

```
BlobClient blobClient = new(new Uri("<The Url you have been given>"));
var result =  blobClient.DownloadContent();
var value = result.Value;
```

However you do need to be clear on the type of resource to which the Url refers. For blobs this could be the Container or an Individual blob. The above code is used for a SAS Token Url for a single blob. If you have a Url for the blob container you need to instantiate a BlobContainerClient.

```
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new(new Uri("<The Url you have been given>"))
```